# GetFileAttributes Function

Tags: c++, visual-c++, msdn

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    DWORD d = GetFileAttributes(argv[0]);
    _TCHAR* temp;
    printf("%d\n", d);
    switch(d)
    {
        case 2048: temp = L"Compressed"; break;
        case 32: temp = L"Archive"; break;
        case 16: temp = L"Directory"; break;
        case 16384: temp = L"Encrypted"; break;
        case 2: temp = L"Hidden"; break;
        case 128: temp = L"Normal"; break;
        case 1: temp = L"Readonly"; break;
        case 4: temp = L"System"; break;
        case 256: temp = L"Temporary"; break;
        default: temp = L"Error or unsupported attribute"; break;
    }
    _tprintf(temp);
    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

what's wrong with this code? I always get 32 in d, even when I launch it with no attributes?
I'm using visual studio 2010.
Thank you!

Comment: As a side note, these values are additive. In other words, it could be compressed and hidden, then the value would be 2048 + 2. In this case, your code would not display the two states that are "on", but instead print and "error" via the `default`.

Comment: Is there anything else I can provide to answer this question?

Answer (score 6):

argv[0] is the name of your executable program.  Simply set the index to 1 (ensure it exists).  You may also want to use a bitwise AND operation to determine if a flag is set.